# parsing json data into csv using pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I am trying to convert the a json file into a csv file using the pandas package in Python.

Code being used:

```
import pandas
json_file = ("/home/joe/Documents/code/facebook/json/message_1.json")
output = pandas.read_json(json_file)
f = open("/home/joe/Documents/code/facebook/csv/test_output.csv", "w+")
f.write(output.to_csv())
```

Sample json:

```
{
  "messages": [
    { 
      "sender_name": "Joe P",
      "timestamp_ms": 1576878720049,
      "content": "message 3",
      "type": "Generic"
    },
    { 
      "sender_name": "Joe P",
      "timestamp_ms": 1576878681386,
      "content": "message 2",
      "type": "Generic"
    },
    {
      "sender_name": "Aimee C",
      "timestamp_ms": 1576878665008,
      "content": "message 1",
      "type": "Generic"
    }
  ]
}
```

i would like the output csv data to be formatted like this:

```
sender_name |timestamp_ms  |content   |type
Joe P       |1576878720049 |Message 3 |generic
Joe P       |1576878681386 |Message 2 |generic
Aimee C     |1576878665008 |Message 1 |generic
```

However, the output data looks like this (only 2 columns instead of 4):

```
    |messages
0   |{'sender_name': 'Joe P', 'timestamp_ms': 1576878720049, 'content': 'message 3', 'type': 'Generic'}
1   |{'sender_name': 'Joe P', 'timestamp_ms': 1576878681386, 'content': 'message 2', 'type': 'Generic'}
2   |{'sender_name': 'Aimee C', 'timestamp_ms': 1576878665008, 'content': 'message 1', 'type': 'Generic'}
```

I've read through lots of threads related to parsing JSON data with pandas but i can't quite pin down the solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `{"key": [v0, v1, ...], ...}` structure pandas assumes `key` is the name of a column, and `v0, v1, ...` are the values of that column, which is exactly the output you're getting. So, you don't want to pass it a dict of lists.

Instead, you want a list, where each value in the list corresponds to an entire row. This is exactly the structure of the values corresponding to the `"messages"` key. So if you simply index your JSON with the `"messages"` key, you'll get an array of rows (dictionaries with column names mapping to values), and you can pass that to Pandas to create a dataframe.

```py
In [87]: import pandas as pd

In [88]: import json

In [89]: sample_json = """
    ...: {
    ...:   "messages": [
    ...:     {
    ...:       "sender_name": "Joe P",
    ...:       "timestamp_ms": 1576878720049,
    ...:       "content": "message 3",
    ...:       "type": "Generic"
    ...:     },
    ...:     {
    ...:       "sender_name": "Joe P",
    ...:       "timestamp_ms": 1576878681386,
    ...:       "content": "message 2",
    ...:       "type": "Generic"
    ...:     },
    ...:     {
    ...:       "sender_name": "Aimee C",
    ...:       "timestamp_ms": 1576878665008,
    ...:       "content": "message 1",
    ...:       "type": "Generic"
    ...:     }
    ...:   ]
    ...: }
    ...: """

In [90]: json_data = json.loads(sample_json)

In [91]: df = pd.DataFrame(json_data["messages"])

In [92]: df
Out[92]:
     content sender_name   timestamp_ms     type
0  message 3       Joe P  1576878720049  Generic
1  message 2       Joe P  1576878681386  Generic
2  message 1     Aimee C  1576878665008  Generic
```

---

If your end goal is to just convert from the JSON to a CSV, you don't even need Pandas here at all. You can just use a `csv.DictWriter` and write the inner dicts directly. For example:

```py
In [95]: import sys

In [96]: import csv

In [97]: writer = csv.DictWriter(sys.stdout, json_data["messages"][0].keys())

In [98]: writer.writeheader()
sender_name,timestamp_ms,content,type

In [99]: writer.writerows(json_data["messages"])
Joe P,1576878720049,message 3,Generic
Joe P,1576878681386,message 2,Generic
Aimee C,1576878665008,message 1,Generic
```